# elasticsearch: Is it safe to reference self in discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch 1.7.x on CentOS

Setting up a 3 node cluster.

IP addresses are:

```
192.168.3.100
192.168.3.101
192.168.3.102
```

For simplicity, we would like to use the same entry in all elasticsearch.yml files.:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.3.100", "192.168.3.101", "192.168.3.102"]
```

Is it OK to reference "yourself" in this list?

(The docs don't make it clear whether this is OK or not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it both ways:

Either reference nodes B and C on node A, nodes A and B on node C and nodes A and C on node B 
...or use the same list of nodes A, B, C on each nodes.

I usually prefer the latter one as you can copy/paste the same list on all your nodes.